# Two way binding in angular taking variable as string not assigning variable property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

html:

```
<div tile-component included-svg='::installController.installUpdatesSvg'></div>
```

Install controller:

```
 **there is a scope variable 'installUpdatesSvg'**
this.installUpdateSvg = 'xyzSvg';
```

directive:

```
.directive('tileComponent',
   ['cvLoc','$timeout','$sce',
     function(cvLoc, $timeout,$sce) {
        return {
            restrict : 'EA',
            transclude : true,
            scope : {
                includedSvg : '=?'

            },
            link : function(scope, ele, attrs) {
                scope.includedSvgHtmlContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(attrs.includedSvg).$$unwrapTrustedValue(); 
            }
]);
```

**Here in attrs.includedSvg, im getting '::installController.installUpdatesSvg' instead of 'xyzSvg';**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this : 
`<div tile-component included-svg='{{ installUpdatesSvg }}'></div>`

And instead using `this.installUpdatesSvg`, use `scope.installUpdatesSvg`

Comment: I dont want to do {{}}, as it will show the svg in html document in browser

Comment: Not sure you can do this or you could create an SVGs object in your directive like : 
`svg = { "toto": "xyzSvg" };`
and in your `included-svg` you just pass the key of your wished SVG "toto" in that case